# Plotting in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of data in a text file (X,Y coordinates which are not sorted). 
I want to plot it using `gnuplot` and connect plotted points using lines.

I tried:

```
plot "a.txt" with lines
```

but it is connecting the first point to the second point and so on. I want it to just connect plotted points, not first to second, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to sort it before `gnuplot` reads it, to do what you want. `gnuplot` implicitly uses the order of data in the file as the information about connection between points. If the X coord is the coordinate you want to connect-the-dots by do this at the command line:

```
sort -n +0 -1 a.txt > b.txt
```

Use `gnuplot` to plot the contents of file "b.txt".  Sometimes a `gnuplot` command like this will help you see the data better:

```
plot 'b.txt' using 1:2 with linespoints
```

That puts a visible mark (an X or triangle or something) at the actual (X,Y) pairs, as well as drawing lines between them.

Answer (score 2):

```
plot "a.txt" with points pointtype 3 pointsize 2
```

I added `pointtype` and `pointsize` just to show other options.

Comment: Wouldn't `with points` leave out the connecting lines?